# Why my EditText is returning null or empty string?

Tags: xml, android-edittext

The code should take two numbers via two edittext fields and on the click of the button the textview should print the result. So, can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sum_button);

    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText n1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_no1);
            EditText n2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_no2);
            TextView sum_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sum_result);
            int sum = 0,i=0,j=0;
            i=Integer.getInteger(n1.getText().toString());
            j=Integer.getInteger(n2.getText().toString());
            sum=i+j;
            sum_result.setText("the sum result is "+ sum);


        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/number_ip_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_no1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_no2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sum_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:background="#550000"
        android:text="sum" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sum_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sum_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml?

Comment: did u try debugging ??? and using Integer.parseInt instead of getInt ??

Answer (score 0):

Its is not the answer, but it will be helpful to finding the issue.

Update your onCreate function to this. and see the logs output on onClick event. let me know the logs output.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sum_button);
        final EditText n1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_no1);
        final EditText n2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_no2);
        final TextView sum_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sum_result);

        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int sum = 0,i=0,j=0;
                Log.i("n1 is:", n1.getText().toString()+" number");
                Log.i("n2 is:", n2.getText().toString()+" number");
                i=Integer.getInteger(n1.getText().toString());
                j=Integer.getInteger(n2.getText().toString());
                sum=i+j;
                sum_result.setText("the sum result is "+ sum);

            }
        });


    }
```